# Read information from Bluetooth NFC reader

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, nfc

I'm trying to make an Android app (Java) that reads the information from an "NFC to Bluetooth reader" (like [this one](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ACR1255U-J1-Android-IOS-Smart-acr1255_62045811087.html)).

Basically, the device will read the information from the NFC and transfer it to Bluetooth.

I'm trying to make an app that reads the information from that device via Bluetooth, but I haven't found any solution.

Is there any link or keyword that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, these Bluetooth readers come with a library. The product you provided sells some development tools that would probably help you integrate it into your application. Though very costly.

I found a [github repository](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api), which provides a library to connect to NFC Readers via USB. Bluetooth connections are supported as Beta for exactly your linked product. So, I think the repository is a good starting point for you.

I personally worked with [these readers](https://www.tertiumtechnology.com/en/product/nfc-scanner/), where a fully functional [library](https://github.com/tertiumtechnology/tt-rfid-passive-api-lib-android) was provided. I can 100% recommend them, however I think they were pretty costly.

***EDIT:*** I looked again on the [website](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/403/acr1255u-j1-acs-secure-bluetooth%C2%AE-nfc-reader/) of your product and they provide some downloads. Two of the downloads are for their sample Android application, which includes the application's source code as well as their library. So, if you got that product simply download their resources and integrate the parts you want in your applcation.